# What's required to read value set in Settings app from my app via NSUserDefault?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, settings

I set a text setting key in by Settings.bundle.
The Settings app show the key's default value well.
But I can't read the value via `NSUserDefaults` with this code.

```
NSString *aaa   =   [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"aaa"] copy];
```

Value is always nil. I believe I omitted something required steps. What's required?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution.

`Settings.bundle` is just for configuration of Settings app, and the default values designated in the file is only for `Settings` app UI. So the `NSUserDefaults` does not read them automatically. At the first time of your app launch, there is no default configuration. So you have to create default values yourself.

I don't remember about execution of Settings app before first launch. As I remember. However, it's obvious you have to offer default value via code if the entries are not exist.